# Measuring distance along a linear shapefile (if possible, not with with command lines)

Tags: distance

I have already asked this but, possibly, I had not well described the issue. I would need to simply measure the distance in meters along the black linear shapefile (they are transects that start from the yellow shapefile of the coastline and intersect the polygonal green shapefile that is the vegetated dune) from the red dot on the left to the red dot on the right (the point where the transect intersects the green shapefile).
I ask if there is a method to do so in a similar way one can measure distances with Google Earth.
I am really not an expert of QGIS and I have never used the command line. So, I ask if it is possible to do without using command lines.
I also ask if it is possible to measure this distance between two well definite points, that is the one on the left that's the left vertex of the transect and the point in which it intersects the green shapefile. It would be ok for me also to repeat the measurement for each transect.

[image]

Comment: please don't just ask the same question again - edit and improve your first question

Answer (score 1):

Run `difference` on your lines, with the lines as the first, and the green polygon as the second input. This leaves the part of the lines outside the polygon.

Then add the length using `$length` in the field calculator - provided your lines layer is in a m-based CRS.